# Installing Cocos-2dx on Windows

Tags: cocos2d-x

I think I am like a lot of other developers who want to use Cocos2dx.  I am on a Windows machine, I have eclipse as my development environment. I don't mind switching to visual studio but I don't want to be half in visual studio and half in eclipse.  I think the lack of tool support is somewhat defeating the cross platform goals here.  What are my options?  I mean if I don't get some good options I might just go with libgdx for android, and cocos2d for iPhone.

Answer (score 6):

You can totally shift on visual studio there is project called VS Android from which you can run android and add cocos2d-x to that project or vice versa

First time you will find it difficult but once you will setup one demo project then you can reuse it with many.

First setup the cocos2d-x project in visual studio after that just add those settings with the VS Android demo project which you can find it in the below steps

or you can do vice versa

you can use visual studoio for android using "VS Android"

Here are the steps to set it up (i) Downloading the SDK and other dependencies:

1) Download the SDK http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

2) Download the NDK http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html 3) Download Cygwin http://cygwin.com/install.html

4) Download the JDK http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

5) Download VS 2010. This version is very essential because VS Android is not compatible with any other VS version http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express-iso

6) Download VS Android http://code.google.com/p/vs-android/

7) Apache Ant download http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi

8) Set environment variables: [ To set environment variables, do: MyComputer->Right click->Properties->Advanced->Environment variables. ] a) ANDROID_NDK_ROOT = :\android-ndk-r8-windows\android-ndk-r8 b) ANT_HOME = :\apache-ant-1.8.4-bin\apache-ant-1.8.4 c) JAVA_HOME = \Java\jdk1.7.0_05 d) _JAVA_OPTIONS = -Xms256m -Xmx512m

9) Download Example from here http://code.google.com/p/vs-android/downloads/detail?name=vs-android_samples.zip

**Note** : 
You wont have any problem if you follow proper steps but some time it gets trial and error method.
I will try to help you as much as I can because I have set it up like that way

**Advantage**:
Debug is amazing in VS 
I am VS user 
I hate eclipse because its buggy

**Disadvantage**
Difficult set up but once you get it ..you get it for lifetime ..
Even if the cocos2d-x version gets updated doesnt matter you just have to copy paste the you cocos2d--x project files in to the new project

Comment: if you know setting up set up cocos2dx in eclipse Android adt please share or update your answer. +1 for your answer.

Comment: @Subra : give me ur email Id i will send you or else ask the question and send me the link so it would be apt to answer over there

Comment: @user1201239 please also send me instructions for setting up cocos2d-x with Android NDK in Windows without Cygwin. Put your instructions in a pastebin.com paste, and share the link here.