# Running Cocos2d-x using vs-android in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, vs-android

I have setup my vs-android with my Visual C++ 2010 Express. I can now run the sample projects of vs-android in my android device.

I followed `user1201239`'s answer in this question [Installing Cocos-2dx on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588955/installing-cocos-2dx-on-windows/12643567#12643567) to setup vs-android/Visual C++ 2010.

This is my question. What are the next steps to integrate cocos2d-x in this setup?